# Compare HTML encoded text to plain text in PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

I have two same strings but one is having HTML entities and the other is its equivalent character:

```
$s1 = "&lsquo;Dragon&rsquo;";
$s2 = "'Dragon'";
```

Is there any way I can detect that both strings are the same? I know that `strcmp` can not be used here and there is no `mb_` function for comparing in PHP. Here is what I did but it is not working:

```
$coll = collator_create( 'en_US' );
$res  = collator_compare( $coll, html_entity_decode($s1), $s2 );

if ($res === false) {
    echo collator_get_error_message( $coll );
} else if( $res > 0 ) {
    echo "s1 is greater than s2\n";
} else if( $res < 0 ) {
    echo "s1 is less than s2\n";
} else {
    echo "s1 is equal to s2\n";
}
```

Comment: you need to convert the encoded string to a decoded string or versa-vice.

Comment: @hassan Can you look at my code and point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@saurabh, in your case you are dealing with the `left single quote` special character. You can convert this to it's character by using the `html_entity_decode` method:

```
$s1 = html_entity_decode($s1) // ‘Dragon’
```

Now you can compare the strings like you normally would do: `$s1 == $s2`

But since your `$s2` doesn't have the `left single quote` but the `apostrophe`, your check will return false. So make sure the characters are the same.

```
$s1 = html_entity_decode("&lsquo;Dragon&rsquo;"); // ‘Dragon’
$s2 = "'Dragon'"; // 'Dragon'

// false because ‘ is not the same as '
return $s1 == $s2; // false
```